# Problems with remote debugging an Android app on my phone

Tags: android, cordova, debugging, remote-debugging

I am developing a cordova Android application and want to remote debug it.
When I start my app on my Android phone thats connected to my Mac I can see the device and the inspectable app webview on Chrome's

```
chrome://inspect/#devices - page.
```

But whenever I click on the 'inspect' link a window opens and at once closes again.
I double checked the android:debugable-flag is set to true in AndroidManifest.xml application element and my device is set to be able to use USB-debugging. I use cordova version: 3.5.0-0.2.6.

Really don't know what went wrong. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What device do you need? http://www.ironlab.io allows debugging on real devices in the cloud. They are in free beta now.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer today after searching the web again. I got to the following document:

[Google remote debugging webviews](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging)

I just had to make sure I use:

[Chrome Canary browser for debugging](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/canary.html)

instead of the normal Chrome browser. I test it and debugging works like a charme.

Just posted this answer as reference for those which got a similar problems.